# How to create signed apk using upload_cert.der file

Tags: android, google-play, android-keystore, android-app-signing

I have read many reference about Google app signing but still did not found my requirement. I have only `upload_cert.der` and `deployment_cert.der` file. I have not access of publisher play store account. I have to only created updated APK and deliver its to client and client will upload it. Now my question is that :

- If i have only `upload_cert.der` and `deployment_cert.der` file then, can we create signed apk which can update existing application on store?
- If above requirement is possible then please explain step by step process of creating signed apk using `upload_cert.der` and `deployment_cert.der` file that can successfully update exiting application.

Comment: checkout this ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103024/how-to-enable-google-play-app-signing

Comment: @KuLdip, I have already mention in our question that I have not account credential. I have only two .der file and the link that is provided by you is not exploring about .der file

Answer (score 1):

The `.der` files are not sufficient to sign anything. You will need the original keystores which contain the private key.

I've explained this in details in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53320907/how-to-use-upload-certificate-to-release-an-app-update/53328732#53328732) before what these files are and what they're used for.